# How to find x coordinate in a tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

So i have a program and need to get the location of a node in the form of coordinates x and y , depending on it's location in a tree, meaning that the x coordinate 0 belongs to the left most Node in the entire tree. For example for a tree like this :

```
    5
      \
        2
       /
      1
     /   
    4
   / 
  3
```

the coordinates should be :

| node | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |

while my code gets me:

| node | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 0 | 4 |

My code :

```
static class Node {
        
        Integer value;
        Node leftNode;
        Node rightNode;
        Integer x;
        Integer y;

        Node ( Integer value, Node left, Node right) {
 
            this.value = value;
            leftNode = left;
            rightNode = right;
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = 0;

        }
}

public static void setCoordinates (Node node, int level, int upperX){
            if (node == null) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                node.y = level;
                node.x = xCordinate(node.leftNode, upperX) ;
                
                System.out.println("x :: " + node.x + " y ::  " + node.y + "  node   ::" + node.value);

                setCoordinates(node.leftNode, level + 1, 0);
                setCoordinates(node.rightNode, level +1 , node.x);
            }
        }
public static void setCoordinates (Node root) {
   // root is a variable defined in main w
            Node n = root;
            int lvl = 0;
            setCoordinates(n, lvl, 0); 
        }

public static int xCordinate (Node n , Integer upperX) {
            if (n == null){
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                int nrOfLeft =  xCordinate(n.leftNode,0);
                int nrOfRight = xCordinate(n.rightNode,0);
                return nrOfLeft + nrOfRight + 1 + upperX;
            }
        }
```

can somebody help me get the correct x coordinate ? The y coordinate isn't giving me any trouble.
Thank you for your help !!

Comment: Can you explain how the coordinate of `5` is `(0,0)`. *the x coordinate 0 belongs to the left most Node in the entire tree* - `5` is not the left most node in the entire tree.

Comment: Yeah since the node 5 doesn’t have any left sons and all the other notes are right decendents of the node it is supposed to be left most element

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int setCoordinates (Node node, int level, int nextX){
            if (node == null) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                nextX = setCoordinates(node.leftNode, level + 1, nextX);
                node.y = level;
                node.x = nextX;
                
                System.out.println("x :: " + node.x + " y ::  " + node.y + "  node   ::" + node.value);


                nextX = setCoordinates(node.rightNode, level +1 , node.x + 1);
                return nextX;
            }
        }
```

You need to keep track of how many nodes are to the left. There might be some from another left branch on an ancestor.

However if you do an in-order traversal you will visit the nodes in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues:

- In the first call of `setCoordinates`, you should not pass 0 as last argument, as the returned value should be at least `upperX`. Change to:

  ```
  setCoordinates(node.leftNode, level + 1, upperX);
  ```
- In the second call of `setCoordinates`, you should not pass `node.x`, as that value is already consumed. You need to pass the *minimum* value that can be attributed, which is one more:

  ```
  setCoordinates(node.rightNode, level + 1, node.x + 1); // <--
  ```
- In `xCordinate` you should never return a value less than `upperX`, so when the node is `null` don't return 0, but:

  ```
  if (n == null){
      return upperX;
  }
  ```

With these changes it will work. However, this is inefficient, as you perform a subtree traversal from *every* node with `xCordinate`, so this will visit the same node potentially many times. You should revise your algorithm so it can do the job in one sweep. For this you need an in-order traversal.